# Key not found, struggling to parse nested JSON in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I'm failing to correctly parse this JSON, I get the following error:

"keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "GameEntries", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"GameEntries\", intValue: nil) (\"GameEntries\").", underlyingError: nil))"

I think my issue is probably due with parsing a dictionary vs an array, but I'm starting to get lost.

JSON:

```
{
    fullgameschedule =     {
        gameentry =         (
                        {
                awayTeam =                 {
                    Abbreviation = SEA;
                    City = Seattle;
                    ID = 123;
                    Name = Mariners;
                };
                date = "2019-03-20";
                homeTeam =                 {
                    Abbreviation = OAK;
                    City = Oakland;
                    ID = 125;
                    Name = Athletics;
                };
                id = 48847;
                location = "Tokyo Dome";
                time = "5:35AM";
            },
                        {
                awayTeam =                 {
                    Abbreviation = CHC;
                    City = Chicago;
                    ID = 131;
                    Name = Cubs;
                };
                date = "2019-09-29";
                homeTeam =                 {
                    Abbreviation = STL;
                    City = "St. Louis";
                    ID = 133;
                    Name = Cardinals;
                };
                id = 48879;
                location = "Busch Stadium";
                time = "3:15PM";
            }
        );
        lastUpdatedOn = "2019-04-27 9:38:51 AM";
    };
}
```

My structs:

```
struct FullGameSchedule: Decodable
{
    let GameEntries: GameEntries
    let lastUpdatedOn: String
}

struct GameEntries: Decodable
{
    let Games = [Game]()
}

struct Game: Decodable
{
    let awayTeam: Team
    let date: String
    let homeTeam: Team
    let id: Int
    let location: String
    let time: String
}

struct Team: Decodable
{
    let Abbreviation: String
    let City :String
    let ID: Int
    let Name:String
}
```

My parsing:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "blah") else { return }

        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data else {return }

            do {

                let games = try JSONDecoder().decode(FullGameSchedule.self, from: data)
                print(games)

                //let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                //print(json)

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
```

My hope is that I can get the JSON into the games objet so that I can then filter down and pull specific details about arbitrary games throughout the season based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

Your property names and first two structs don't match your JSON. You need:

```
struct FullGameSchedule: Decodable
{
    let fullgameschedule: GameEntries
}

struct GameEntries: Decodable
{
    let gameentry: [Game]
    let lastUpdatedOn: String
}
```

You may also wish to make use of specifying CodingKeys so you can properly name your struct properties with appropriate camelCase.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

I'll go look into CodingKeys

Comment: While this works, GameEntries is an empty array, any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean that `gameentry` is an empty array? And edit your question and post the actual JSON and not the output of printing a dictionary.

Comment: See my updated answer. There was a typo on the `gameentry` line.